# handling "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null" error

Tags: javascript, angular

I just started with angular. I was being told to handle the above error by using try-catch and display the proper message on HTML. I searched on the internet about error handling but I couldn't find a link about try-catch. if there is any other method please mention it. I am giving the error snap below and also posting the code where the error has occurred. thanks in advance.

[image: error image]

```
            self.bulkQuestions[quesNo - 1]['category'] = self.items.value[itemIndex].category.split('|')[1];
```

Comment: it is saying, probably `category` is null. make sure you have data before accessing

Comment: yes exactly need to handle that error and display some customized message and I don't need to fix the error. I need to handle it.

Comment: try `self.items.value[itemIndex].category && self.items.value[itemIndex].category.split('|')[1] || "your_default_value"`

Comment: how can I print a message in Html using this method? please write your answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just go with the below code

```
try{
   self.bulkQuestions[quesNo - 1]['category'] = self.items.value[itemIndex].category.split('|')[1];

}
catch(e){
console.log('some message')
}
```

Comment: what if I get the same error for another 3 more same statements

Comment: you can add all your possible error raising code in `try` block

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
self.bulkQuestions[quesNo - 1]['category'] = self.items.value[itemIndex].category ? self.items.value[itemIndex].category.split('|')[1] : '<span>Your message</span>';
```

Comment: what ```is:' ';``` ?

Comment: If there is no value then is just blank or do what ever you want here

Comment: you can also use only if(self.items.value[itemIndex].category).

Comment: how can I print a message in Html using this method

Comment: Code updated please check I an using <span> but you can use any HTML teg or a plain text according to your requirment.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the context of your code and the result you're looking to achieve.
For example, if you need to guard the execution, you could do the following:

```
if (itemIndex && self.items.value[itemIndex] && self.items.value[itemIndex].category) {
   self.bulkQuestions[quesNo - 1]['category'] = self.items.value[itemIndex].category.split('|')[1];
}
```

You can pad this block for further execution.